# I want to know how to simplify multiple binding with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to connect to several Kafka brokers using Spring Cloud Stream.
At runtime I want to avoid binding to a particular broker when I have a particular profile or condition.

The code below is a sample I developed.

```
@Profile({"b","c"})
@EnableBinding(AConsumer.AChanel.class)
public class AConsumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @StreamListener(AConsumer.AChanel.INPUT)
    public void subscribe(String message, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
        logger.info("i receive message(A) --> message : {}", message);
    }

    public interface AChanel {
        public static final String INPUT = "a_input";
        @Input(INPUT) SubscribableChannel aInput();
    }

}
```

```
@Profile({"a","c"})
@EnableBinding(BConsumer.BChanel.class)
public class BConsumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @StreamListener(BConsumer.BChanel.INPUT)
    public void subscribe(String message, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
        logger.info("i receive message(B) --> message : {}", message);
    }

    public interface BChanel {
        public static final String INPUT = "b_input";
        @Input(INPUT) SubscribableChannel bInput();
    }
}
```

```
@Profile({"a","b"})
@EnableBinding(CConsumer.CChanel.class)
public class CConsumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @StreamListener(CConsumer.CChanel.INPUT)
    public void subscribe(String message, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
        logger.info("i receive message(C) --> message : {}", message);
    }

    public interface CChanel {
        public static final String INPUT = "c_input";
        @Input(INPUT) SubscribableChannel cInput();
    }

}
```

Is not there a better way than this?
I think there is another way to use annotation(like Conditional or other) or customize the spring cloud stream 
library.

Anyone who knows, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think profiles is a best way to handle this.

Based on my understanding of your requirement the above could easily be handled with different property values or even further, with property resolvers

1. You can simply define your properties at the startup via command line, config server and many other ways
2. You can define your properties statically let's say in yaml or properties file and then use standard property resolution notation to supply the actual values

   `spring.cloud.stream.someproperty=${someproperty.value}`